# BibFuse: What language is this, and how can I modify it?

Tags: ms-word, bibtex, bibliography

I write a lot of scientific papers, and have been recently forced to work with MS Word. I use BibDesk as my reference manager on a Mac OS, and have found [bibfuse](http://bibfuse.sourceforge.net) to be a nice way of citing papers in Word from BibDesk. The problem is that bibfuse only handles journal articles. It does not work very well at citing books, book entries (i.e., "incollection" entries in BibDesk), and websites. Does anyone know how to add to or modify the sampletemplate.doc file in the bibfuse package to accept these entries? The sampletemplate.doc file contains only the following lines of code:

```
<$publications>
<$itemIndex/>.  
<$pubAuthors.unpunctuatedAbbreviatedNormalizedName.stringByRemovingTeX.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAmpersand/> (<$pubFields.Year/>) <$pubFields.Title/>. <$pubFields.Journal/> 
<$pubFields.Volume/>, <$pubFields.Pages/>.
</$publications>
```

If no one knows how to do that, can anyone tell me what language this is, so I might figure it out and modify if possible?